# SymmetricDS pk alternative

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

After reading the SymmetricDS userguide I'm not sure if SymmetricDS supports conflict resolution which is not based on PK but **exclusively** on my own custom columns.

Given the following scenario:

- 2 nodes with bi-directional update
- each node has one table `products` which must be synchronized

Now, the table schema looks like this (simplified):

```
id (pk) |  name (char)  | reference (char)
```

What I would like to know is, is it possible to define the column `reference` as identifier for conflict resolution and insert / update operations instead of the pk column `id`?

**Example:**

```
Node0
id (pk) |  name (char)  | reference (char)
1          Foo            IN001
2          FooBaz         IN003
----

Node1
id (pk) |  name (char)  | reference (char)
1          Bar            EX001
2          Foo            IN001
```

Changes on row 2 in Node1 will trigger updates on row 1 in Node 1 while creating a new record in Node0/1 will trigger an insert in the respective node but considering that the PK might be already taken.

Furthermore I would like to filter the to be synchronized table rows by the value of column `reference`. Which means that **only** rows should by synced where `reference startwith('IN') == True`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change your db schema? Can you make name the PK and and drop id? How do you want to handle the situation where the PK is already taken?

You can use a [Bean Shell Router](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_beanshell_router) to determine which records get synced.

Comment: (1) I can not change the db schema

(2) I can not drop PK 

(3) Actually I do not care about the PK, that means if the PK is already taken I take a new one in the node's `product` table. The matching must be working on the `reference` column.

Comment: Hello Malte, I am not able to register my application with symmetric ds, Can you please tell me how I can registered my app. My logcat error is: unable to handle unkonown csv files

Answer (score 2):

Look at the column 'SYNC_KEY_NAMES' on the TRIGGER table.

> Specify a comma-delimited list of columns that should be used as the
>   key for synchronization operations. By default, if not specified, then
>   the primary key of the table will be used.

If you insert the value 'name' into this column, SDS will handle it as the PK.

Leaving id as a PK creates a hurdle. If this column auto-increments, you can try to exclude it in the trigger table column, 'EXCLUDED_COLUMN_NAMES'. Since this is the PK, I don't know if SDS will ignore it or not.

If that does not work you will have to write a [Custom Load Filter](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_load_filter_scripts) to increment the id field on insert.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that solution and let you know.

Comment: It seems that my scenario can not be accomplished so easy.

Comment: 1. If add a excluded column in the trigger table the target node table will be altered --> the excluded column will be deleted from the table schema!

2. Using the `sync_key_names` in the trigger table will alter the target node table --> removing the PK from id and setting it to the column `reference`.

Both alter operations are not acceptable for me! Finally I have to code some extensive extensions, what I do not want to!

Comment: Based on your description, I agree with Austin.  sync_key_names is what you are looking for.  Setting sync_key_names will not alter your table.